# How much time (Big-O) will an algorithm take which can rule out one third of possible numbers from 1 to N in each step?

Tags: big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I am abstracting the problem out. (it has nothing to do with prime numbers)
How much time (in terms of Big-O) will it take to determine if `n` is the solution?
If suppose I was able to design an algorithm which can rule out one third of the numbers from the possible answers `{1,2,...,n}` in the first step. Then successively rules out one third of the "remaining" numbers until all numbers are tested.

I have thought a lot about it but cant figure out it will be `O(n log₃(n))` or `O(log₃(n))`

Comment: O(log N) algorithm would be too cool thing to design. Don't take the offence, please, but I doubt, you do.

Comment: What means O(N log N)? Is it worse than just check all numbers 1..N?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the algorithm, and on the value of N. You should be able to figure out and program an algorithm that takes O (sqrt (N)) rather easily, and it's not difficult to go down to O (sqrt (N) / log N). Anything better requires some rather deep mathematics, but there *are* algorithms that are a lot faster for large N.

Now when you say O (N log N), please don't guess these things. O (N log N) is ridiculous. The most stupid algorithm where you use nothing than the definition of a prime number is O (N).

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, the best effort is O(log^3 N), but the corresponding algorithm is not something you could figure out easily. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test

There are more practical probabilistic algorithms though.

BTW. About 'ruling out one third' etc. It does not matter would it be 'log base 3' or 'log base 10' and so on. O(log N) roughly means 'any base logarithm' because they all can be reduced to each other by constant multiplier only. So the complexity of such algorithm will be log N * complexity_of_reduction_step. But the problem is, that 'single step' will hardly take the constant time. And if so, it will not help in achieving O(log N).